Problem with the responsive image in the hero section that shrinks before the set width
What I want
What I'm seeing
I'm working on making a responsive hero section where I want the image to stay full size until the window width drops below 1300px. However, I have noticed that the image starts to shrink much earlier, and I am not sure why this is happening.
Here is my HTML and CSS code:


/* *************** */
/* HERO-SECTION */
/* *************** */

.hero {
  max-width: 130rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 9.6rem;
}

.hero h1 {
  font-size: 5.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 3.2rem;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.hero p {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 4.8rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1.2rem 3.2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #e67e22;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.left:hover,
.left:active {
  background-color: #cf711f;
}

.right:link,
.right:visited {
  background-color: white;
  color: #333;
  margin-left: 2.4rem;
}

.right:hover,
.right:active {
  background-color: #fdf2e9;
  color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px white;
}

.hero-section {
  background-color: #fdf2e9;
  padding: 16rem 32rem;
}

.head-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.deliver-ithems {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 8rem;
  gap: 1.6rem;
}

.deliver-imgs {
  display: flex;
}

.deliver-imgs img {
  height: 4.8rem;
  width: 4.8rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: #fff solid 2px;
  margin-left: -1.6rem;
}

.deliver-imgs img:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.deliver-text {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.deliver-ithems span {
  color: #cf711f;
}
<header class="hero-section">
  <div class="hero">
    <div class="head-text">
      <div class="text-section">
        <h1>
          A healthy meal <br />delivered to your door, <br />every single day
        </h1>
        <p>
          The smart 365-days-per-year food subscription that will make you eat healthy again. Tailored to your personal tastes and nutritional needs.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn left">Start eating well</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn right">Learn more &darr;</a>
        <div class="deliver-ithems">
          <div class="deliver-imgs">
            <img src="img/customers/customer-1.jpg" alt="customer" />
            <img src="img/customers/customer-2.jpg" alt="customer" />
            <img src="img/customers/customer-3.jpg" alt="customer" />
            <img src="img/customers/customer-4.jpg" alt="customer" />
            <img src="img/customers/customer-5.jpg" alt="customer" />
            <img src="img/customers/customer-6.jpg" alt="customer" />
          </div>
          <div class="deliver-text">
            <span>250,000+</span> meals delivered last year
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-hero">
      <img src="hero.png" alt="tri slike" class="head-img" />
    </div>
  </div>
</header>



I try with normal width and that's it. I'm sure I did everything that made sense to me.

You can use a pixel value to .head-img image width rather than 100%. Then you can use media queries to reduce with when device width reaches to 1300px.
Here you can see how I did that.


/* *************** */
/* HERO-SECTION */
/* *************** */

.hero {
    max-width: 130rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    column-gap: 9.6rem;
}

.hero h1 {
    font-size: 5.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 3.2rem;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.hero p {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 4.8rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 1.2rem 3.2rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #e67e22;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.left:hover,
.left:active {
    background-color: #cf711f;
}

.right:link,
.right:visited {
    background-color: white;
    color: #333;
    margin-left: 2.4rem;
}

.right:hover,
.right:active {
    background-color: #fdf2e9;
    color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px white;
}

.hero-section {
    background-color: #fdf2e9;
    padding: 16rem 32rem;
}

.head-img {
    width: 600px;
}

.deliver-ithems {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 8rem;
    gap: 1.6rem;
}

.deliver-imgs {
    display: flex;
}

.deliver-imgs img {
    height: 4.8rem;
    width: 4.8rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: #fff solid 2px;
    margin-left: -1.6rem;
}

.deliver-imgs img:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}

.deliver-text {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.deliver-ithems span {
    color: #cf711f;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    .head-img {
        width: 400px;
    }
}



Here is my output.

